# Modify the names of a named list in R based on a logic

Tags: r, list, function, rename

In `My_list` below, I want to modify the elements' names based on the following logic:

1. Pick the repeated word in the name (ex. `beginner` in `"(beginner_post1 - beginner_baseline)"`)
2. Pick the numeric in the NON-repeated name (ex. `1` in `"post1"`)
3. Modify the name to `"Gain_numeric(repeated word)"` (ex. `Gain_1(beginner)`)

Is it possible to apply this logic to achieve my `Desired_output` below?

```
My_list = 
  list("(beginner_post1 - beginner_baseline)"= c(5,-2),
       "(intermediate_post1 - intermediate_baseline)"= c(6,-3),
       "(advanced_post1 - advanced_baseline)"= c(4,-1),
       "(beginner_post2 - beginner_baseline)"= c(8,-2),
       "(intermediate_post2 - intermediate_baseline)"= c(9,-3),
       "(advanced_post2 - advanced_baseline)"= c(7,-1),
       "(framework notes_posttest1 - framework notes_baseline)"=c(1,2),
       "(note-taking instruction_posttest1 - note-taking instruction_baseline)"=1
  )


Desired_output = 
  list("Gain_1(beginner)"= c(5,-2),
       "Gain_1(intermediate)"= c(6,-3),
       "Gain_1(advanced)"= c(4,-1),
       "Gain_2(beginner)"= c(8,-2),
       "Gain_2(intermediate)"= c(9,-3),
       "Gain_2(advanced)"= c(7,-1),
       "Gain_1(framework notes)" = c(1,2),
       "Gain_1(note-taking instruction)"=1
)
```

Comment: Just the regex replace: https://regex101.com/r/AI6WNG/1

Comment: @Nick - post that as an answer: `sub("\\(([a-z]+)\\w+?(\\d+)\\W+\\1\\w+\\)", "Gain_\\2(\\1)", names(My_list))` is the R translation with some extra escaping and stuck into `sub`

Comment: @thelatemail, thank you. I updated my post to refelect a pattern I missed in my post (existance of white space and/or dashes). Could one of you guys possibly post an answer?

Comment: @thelatemail modified to take account of OPs changes and posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res <- setNames(My_list, sub("^.([^_]+)\\D+(\\d+).*", "Gain_\\2(\\1)", names(My_list)))

$`Gain_1(beginner)`
[1]  5 -2

$`Gain_1(intermediate)`
[1]  6 -3

$`Gain_1(advanced)`
[1]  4 -1

$`Gain_2(beginner)`
[1]  8 -2

$`Gain_2(intermediate)`
[1]  9 -3

$`Gain_2(advanced)`
[1]  7 -1

$`Gain_1(framework notes)`
[1] 1 2

$`Gain_1(note-taking instruction)`
[1] 1
```

Comment: Note that this regex doesn't enforce that the first word is repeated (which is fine based on OPs sample data)

Comment: Hi Onyambu, it seems your regex: `"^.([^_]+)\\D+(\\d+).*", "Gain_\\2(\\1)"` doesn't follow the 3-step logic I defined in my post. For example, if the name of the last element of `My_list` is reordered from  `(note-taking instruction_posttest1 - note-taking instruction_baseline)`  to  `(posttest1_note-taking instruction - baseline_note-taking instruction)`, then, your regex stops to work. Can you possibly modify your regex so it's not sensitive to the order of the terms in the list names?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
\(([a-z -]+)\w+?(\d+)\W+\1\w+\)
```

which matches:

- `\(` : a `(`
- `([a-z -]+)` : some number of letter, space and hyphen characters, captured in group 1
- `\w+?` : a minimal number of word characters
- `(\d+)` : some number of digits, captured in group 2
- `\W+` : some number of non-word characters
- `\1` : repeat of what was captured in group 1
- `\w+` : some number of word characters
- `\)` : a `)`

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vIkhuA/1)

In R (thanks @thelatemail):

```r
sub("\\(([a-z -]+)\\w+?(\\d+)\\W+\\1\\w+\\)", "Gain_\\2(\\1)", names(My_list))
```