# Remove elements of a named list based on the naming match in R

Tags: r, list, function, tidyverse, rename

Please note: this question is completely different from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78044966/7223434).

In `My_list` below, I wonder how to eliminate whole elements whose names' prefix `"Gain"` has a different number attached to it?

For example, element #1's name is: `Gain1(conventional) - Gain2(conventional)`, therefore, this element must be **REMOVED** because we have `Gain1` vs. `Gain2`.

But element #2's name is: `Gain1(conventional) - Gain1(framework notes)`, therefore, this element must be **KEPT** because we have `Gain1` vs. `Gain1`.

Is this possible in R?

```
My_list <-

list(`Gain1(conventional) - Gain2(conventional)` = c(5L, -1L, 
-9L, 1L), `Gain1(conventional) - Gain1(framework notes)` = c(5L, 
-1L, -6L, 2L), `Gain1(conventional) - Gain2(framework notes)` = c(5L, 
-1L, -10L, 2L), `Gain1(conventional) - Gain1(note-taking instruction)` = c(5L, 
-1L, -7L, 3L), `Gain1(conventional) - Gain2(note-taking instruction)` = c(5L, 
-1L, -11L, 3L), `Gain1(conventional) - Gain1(vocabulary notebook)` = c(5L, 
-1L, -8L, 4L), `Gain1(conventional) - Gain2(vocabulary notebook)` = c(5L, 
-1L, -12L, 4L), `Gain2(conventional) - Gain1(framework notes)` = c(9L, 
-1L, -6L, 2L), `Gain2(conventional) - Gain2(framework notes)` = c(9L, 
-1L, -10L, 2L), `Gain2(conventional) - Gain1(note-taking instruction)` = c(9L, 
-1L, -7L, 3L), `Gain2(conventional) - Gain2(note-taking instruction)` = c(9L, 
-1L, -11L, 3L), `Gain2(conventional) - Gain1(vocabulary notebook)` = c(9L, 
-1L, -8L, 4L), `Gain2(conventional) - Gain2(vocabulary notebook)` = c(9L, 
-1L, -12L, 4L), `Gain1(framework notes) - Gain2(framework notes)` = c(6L, 
-2L, -10L, 2L), `Gain1(framework notes) - Gain1(note-taking instruction)` = c(6L, 
-2L, -7L, 3L), `Gain1(framework notes) - Gain2(note-taking instruction)` = c(6L, 
-2L, -11L, 3L), `Gain1(framework notes) - Gain1(vocabulary notebook)` = c(6L, 
-2L, -8L, 4L), `Gain1(framework notes) - Gain2(vocabulary notebook)` = c(6L, 
-2L, -12L, 4L), `Gain2(framework notes) - Gain1(note-taking instruction)` = c(10L, 
-2L, -7L, 3L), `Gain2(framework notes) - Gain2(note-taking instruction)` = c(10L, 
-2L, -11L, 3L), `Gain2(framework notes) - Gain1(vocabulary notebook)` = c(10L, 
-2L, -8L, 4L), `Gain2(framework notes) - Gain2(vocabulary notebook)` = c(10L, 
-2L, -12L, 4L), `Gain1(note-taking instruction) - Gain2(note-taking instruction)` = c(7L, 
-3L, -11L, 3L), `Gain1(note-taking instruction) - Gain1(vocabulary notebook)` = c(7L, 
-3L, -8L, 4L), `Gain1(note-taking instruction) - Gain2(vocabulary notebook)` = c(7L, 
-3L, -12L, 4L), `Gain2(note-taking instruction) - Gain1(vocabulary notebook)` = c(11L, 
-3L, -8L, 4L), `Gain2(note-taking instruction) - Gain2(vocabulary notebook)` = c(11L, 
-3L, -12L, 4L), `Gain1(vocabulary notebook) - Gain2(vocabulary notebook)` = c(8L, 
-4L, -12L, 4L))
```

Comment: I think this (and OP's previous question) may very well be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  If the data is refactored to have elements, say, `LHS`, `RHS` (both with values "Gain1" and "Gain2"), `Source` (with values "conventional", "vocabulary notebook", etc) and `Value` (or to a data frame with similar columns), then I think the difficulty goes away: it essentially degenerates to `Gain1 == Gain2`.

Comment: SimonHarmel, I've seen some of your other questions (or at least questions that have identically-structured named lists like this), and it most definitely seems a difficult way to manage data. I agree with Limey that many of the problems you're experiencing might be eased by adopting a more "tidy" data structure. How you form this depends on the original source (how you're importing it), but you may want to consider adapting your process to be more "observation" based. With or without the tidyverse, there are many benefits to doing so.

Comment: @r2evans, thank you. Unfortunately, in my case I don't have full access to the data source. In other words, steps prior to where I get the data are not in my control to redefine them. But I truly appreciate all members' sincere contributions. This is really valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a regex on `names(My_list)` and extract the `Gain#`.

```r
samegain <- strcapture("Gain([0-9]+).*Gain([0-9]+)", names(My_list), list(g1=0L, g2=0L)) |>
  with(g1 == g2)
samegain
#  [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [17]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
My_list[samegain]
# $`Gain1(conventional) - Gain1(framework notes)`
# [1]  5 -1 -6  2
# $`Gain1(conventional) - Gain1(note-taking instruction)`
# [1]  5 -1 -7  3
# $`Gain1(conventional) - Gain1(vocabulary notebook)`
# [1]  5 -1 -8  4
# $`Gain2(conventional) - Gain2(framework notes)`
# [1]   9  -1 -10   2
# $`Gain2(conventional) - Gain2(note-taking instruction)`
# [1]   9  -1 -11   3
# $`Gain2(conventional) - Gain2(vocabulary notebook)`
# [1]   9  -1 -12   4
# $`Gain1(framework notes) - Gain1(note-taking instruction)`
# [1]  6 -2 -7  3
# $`Gain1(framework notes) - Gain1(vocabulary notebook)`
# [1]  6 -2 -8  4
# $`Gain2(framework notes) - Gain2(note-taking instruction)`
# [1]  10  -2 -11   3
# $`Gain2(framework notes) - Gain2(vocabulary notebook)`
# [1]  10  -2 -12   4
# $`Gain1(note-taking instruction) - Gain1(vocabulary notebook)`
# [1]  7 -3 -8  4
# $`Gain2(note-taking instruction) - Gain2(vocabulary notebook)`
# [1]  11  -3 -12   4
```

Variants: if you have entries that is missing either `Gain`, then:

1. If you need to *keep* them, then:

   ```r
   strcapture("Gain([0-9]+).*Gain([0-9]+)", names(My_list), list(g1=0L, g2=0L)) |>
     with(is.na(g1) | is.na(g2) | g1 == g2)
   ```
2. If you need to *discard* entries without `Gain#`, then:

   ```r
   strcapture("Gain([0-9]+).*Gain([0-9]+)", names(My_list), list(g1=0L, g2=0L)) |>
     with(!is.na(g1) & !is.na(g2) & g1 == g2)
   ```